# S3 PUT gives 200 OK response but the file isn't always uploaded

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload files to a pre-signed S3 URL. This works fine about half the time. However, the other half the time the file simply hasn't been uploaded to the S3.

I'm using the following snippet to do the heavy lifting:

```
let preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "");
let blob = b64toBlob(file.fileString, result.ContentType);

const resp = await axios.put(
    preSignedUrl,
    { data: blob },
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": result.ContentType,
        },
    });
```

If I upload through Postman and not the browser, it's consistently fine.

The blob, the URL and the content-type are all correct. I'm always uploading to the same bucket. I can consistently upload a file, delete it, and then re-upload the same file and it won't have uploaded the second time.

I *always* get a 200 OK response from S3.

Am I missing anything obvious in my request format? Are there any 'gotchas' around this approach? Is it possible for S3 to return a 200 without actually accepting the file?

I've tried looking for similar issues but I've not had any luck.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual request / response, and compared it to Postmate's? If so, providing the request (sans payload and keys, of course :)) in your question might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out the cause and solution; I just misinterpreted what was going on with the promises.

This turned out to be caused by some of the other stuff on the page we were working on.

The full file-upload code we had was (with *fetch* instead of *axios*, in the end):

```
async function uploadFiles() {
  let requestArray = files.map(file => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      handleDocs.GenerateUrl(file.fileName, "{!OppName}", async (result, event) => {
        let preSignedUrl = result.Data.toString().replace(/amp;/gm, "");
        let blob = b64toBlob(file.fileString, result.ContentType);

        await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: blob,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": result.ContentType,
          },
        });

        resolve();
      });
    });
  });

  await Promise.all(requestArray);
  document.location.reload();
}
```

Part of the functionality we had was the ability to delete documents from S3, which is done with a call to an API we've written.

As part of our testing, we'd upload a file, delete it and then re-upload it, which is when we would see this issue.

As it turns out, `document.location.reload();` is resubmitting the delete data as part of the page reload. Changing this to `window.location.href = window.location.href;` fixed the problem we were having.

Thanks for the help!